# Foward calls with Twilio, but only answer if the called person answers

Tags: php, twilio

I am trying to forward calls to my Twilio number to a normal landline number.
With `<dial>` this works well, but—

When I call the Twilio number, Twilio answers and then tries to connect to the forwarding number. This means that the caller does not hear the ring (his phone stays silent) until the called person answers. I don't care about the 1¢/min when Twilio answers, but I want the caller to hear a ring until the callee answers.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

In this scenario I would recommend taking a look at the [forwarding Twimlet](https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/forward?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon). I think this will do exactly what you want out of the box.

If not, could you share some sample code from your app?